# Absurd java code in code question how to answer one way?

Tags: parameters

I am new to java programming and have only taken an introduction course.

I need to understand what this Java code means. Can someone explain this?

public class ShapeAreas {

public double oneParameter(String shape, float p1)

{

float area;

if (shape.equals("C"))

return p1 * p1 * Math.PI;

else if (shape.equals("S"))

return p1 * p1;

else

return -1.0;

}

public double twoParameter(String shape, float p1, float p2)

{

float area;

if (shape.equals("R"))

return p1 * p2;

else if (shape.equals("T"))

return 0.5 * p1 * p2;

else

return -1.0;

}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“C” = circle “S” = square “R” = rectangle “T” = triangle

These methods are just returning the area of shapes

This is a class called Shape Areas. It has 2 different methods for calculating the area of a shape based on the inputs. First method works for square and circle, the second works for rectangle and triangle.